# php include ÅÄÖ = ??? / UTF8 problem

Tags: php, utf-8, include

index.php

```
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
```

header.php

```
<?php
echo"<a href='add.php'>Lägg Till</a>";
?>
```

result

```
L?gg Till
```

The document is utf8 within the head tags and all, it's a php thing, the problem only occurs when i get text from include, i cannot have ÅÄÖ in included php files , how do i make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save these files in utf-8 too

Answer (score 2):

when sending text to server with accents letters use always ut8_encode, in you case:

```
echo utf8_encode("<a href='add.php'>Lägg Till</a>");
```

I have the same problem and this on solves them.

Answer (score 0):

Besides saving the file in UTF-8 you could also check the "default_charset" configuration in the php.ini file.

Comment: And check the editor (and if necessary, terminal) are also in UTF-8. It's possible to enter what appears to be UTF-8, but actually isn't.